# Android Console Play - Internal testing - App cannot be found after installation

Tags: android, testing, internals

I have pushed a new release on an existing app on Android through the Google Play Store Internal testing.
Everything seems to work fine:

- Release created
- Release uploaded to Google Play Store in Internal Tests section
- I sent the email to the internal testers with the relevant link
- Once they agreed to participate, they are directed to the Play Store
- They are able to install the new version

However once the installation is done, the application is nowhere to be found on their mobile and they cannot Open it from the Play Store. They can only uninstall it...
Uninstall / Reinstall doesn't help...

I know there can be some time before a release is available but I understood that it's only for 1st version of an application. Here it's an update.
Also it's very strange that they can install the new version without being able to open it after that..

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find out thanks to some help from Google support.
I was missing an intent for my launcher activity.
So I added the following code in my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
</intent-filter>
```

It seems obvious but everything was working fine up to the Play Store publication of the release.

Thanks to the hint given by Google Support team which led me to the solution.